# Presentation time of an access unit for MPEG2-TS

Tags: video-streaming, h.264, vlc, video-processing, mpeg2-ts

Can someone please help me about the times when exactly the access units are displayed in vlc when it plays a TS file?

For elaboration, we provide **PCR_base and PCR_ext in each TS packet**, **PTS in each PES packet**(for the time being I am **not providing DTS value**; is it okay?). 

Consider for ex, PCR_base = 18900000, PCR_ext = 0 for TS packets.

And PTS = 0 for the first PES packet, **incrementing by (90000/25)** as my video is 25 fps.

First of all, is this approach right?

I found **some jerking** in the output video. What can be the reasons?

Answer (score 0):

The jerking is the lack of DTS value. Out of order frames require both PTS and DTS to determine the display order. PCR is only required needed every 100ms, but have it more is ok.